# Python stdout to queue broker or a websocket

Tags: python, websocket, stdout, message-queue

Is there a way to push `stdout` into a queue broker or to a websocket?

So far I've been unable to find a clear explanation on how to do this.

I have several processes running in parallel and the idea is to create a UI where you can switch from process to process and take a look at what they are doing.

Answer (score 0):

One approach that will work (and is non-blocking, can serve multiple clients) is using Python, Twisted and Autobahn:

Connect one or multiple ProcessProtocol instances

- http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/process.html

to a Twisted WebSocket server

- https://github.com/tavendo/AutobahnPython
- https://github.com/tavendo/AutobahnPython/tree/master/examples/websocket/broadcast
- https://github.com/tavendo/AutobahnPython/tree/master/examples/wamp/pubsub/simple

Disclosure: I am author of Autobahn.